# Implementing a NSService method

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift

I created a Service for my app, the menu appears correctly, but I still have a problem with the method called when the menu item is activated.

In AppDelegate.swift I have:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().servicesProvider = ServiceProvider()
    NSUpdateDynamicServices();
}
```

And the class ServiceProvider is:

```
import Cocoa

class ServiceProvider {
    func serviceTest(pasteboard: NSPasteboard, userData: String, error: NSErrorPointer) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

When the service is activated I want to send some information to the components of my app, for example, to change the text of a label. How can I do this? I tried to get the mainWindow inside the function serviceTest to access its components, but it returned nil.

I am trying to do something similar to the Safari service that you select some text, and right-click > services > search with google. This open Safari and search for the selected text. Or something similar to add a new task to Wunderlist, that gets the selected text and create a new task in the app.

I really appreciate some help to solve this issue.

Comment: How did you get the service to appear in the right click services menu? Mine won't even show on the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the general problem of getting access to objects in various parts of a program. There are two general mechanisms: start with a well-known object or have the object(s) you need passed in to you by the part of the code which knows about both object.

For example, you can get to the application delegate using `NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate`. You would then cast it to your custom app delegate class and access its properties.

However, it's probably better to avoid relying on pseudo-global variables if there's a simple alternative, and there is. Give your `ServiceProvider` class the necessary properties to track the objects it needs (like the app delegate). In the app delegate code which creates the `ServiceProvider` instance, simply set those properties. That may be in statements to set properties after it has been created or you could pass it in to the initializer method as an argument. Obviously, you'd need to declare that initializer method to take the argument and store it in your instance variable.

Comment: I see. But, how to get the mainWindow from appDelegate? I saw searching the web that I can use: NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow, but this way mainWindow is nil, so the app crash if I tried to get some properties of mainWindow.

Comment: If `NSApplication.sharedApplication().mainWindow` is `nil`, then your app doesn't have a main window. Did you create a window? Did you order it onto the screen with something like `makeKeyAndOrderFront()` (or other combination of the `NSWindow` `order...()` methods and `makeMainWindow()`)? If you're expecting to access the window of the app which invoked the service, you can't.

Comment: My app works just fine, and it has a main window. Also, I am not using anything related to order. Should I use? Last, I am trying to access the main window of my app, but the service is invoked in other apps, exactly as google search service of Safari or add task service of Wunderlist.

Comment: `NSApplication`'s `mainWindow` property is `nil` when the app is not active (because the window is not the overall main window at that time). You should create an outlet for your app's primary window in your app delegate if you don't already have such a thing. If your app is document based or otherwise has multiple windows, you'll need to track the window you want to work with some other way, such as observing `NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification` and remembering the last one.

Comment: I think I solve the problem. I have a custom controller for the main window, so the outlets are in this controller, not in the AppDelegate. I moved everything of the servicesProvider (its setup and its method) to the custom controller, and now I can set properties of the outlets. Is this a good way to organize the outlets in the custom controller instead in the app delegate?

Thank you so much Ken.

Comment: It's hard to know without knowing your overall design, but your outlets are probably fine. It might also be fine to move the service providing code to that same controller, but it shouldn't be necessary. Couldn't a separate `ServiceProvider` class be given a reference to that controller? Doesn't the app delegate have such a reference?

Comment: Yes, I can pass the reference of the controller to other class, no problem with this. About get the NSWindowController from the AppDelegate, I am not sure how to do this or if I can.